# INotifyPropertyChanged 'Double' binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm trying to bind some XAML code to a property in my ViewModel.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding HasMovies, Converter={StaticResources VisibilityConverter}}">
...
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel is setup like this:

```
private bool _hasMovies;
        public bool HasMovies
        {
            get { return _hasMovies; }
            set { _hasMovies = value; RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies"); }
        }
```

In the constructor of the ViewModel, I set the HasMovies link:

```
MovieListViewModel()
{
   HasMovies = CP.Connection.HasMovies;
}
```

in CP:

```
public bool HasMovies
        {
            get { return MovieList != null && MovieList.Count > 0; }
        }

private ObservableCollection<Movie> _movies;
        public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieList
        {
            get { return _movies; }
            set
            {
                _movies = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MovieList");
                RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies");
                _movies.CollectionChanged += MovieListChanged;
            }
        }

        private void MovieListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies");
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I change this binding so that it reflects the current state of `CP.Connection.HasMovies`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either directly expose the object in the ViewModel and bind directly through that (so that the value is not just copied once which is what happens now) or subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event and set HasMovies to the new value every time it changes in your source object.

e.g.

```
CP.Connection.PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName = "HasMovies") this.HasMovies = CP.Connection.HasMovies;
    };
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for, but the first idea to bind directly to the object sounds like a good idea, since I use this property in quite a few places. Do you have an example of how to do this binding in XAML?

Comment: That's a awful silly solution, and still wouldn't work, as the PropertyChanged event is **not** called for when adding or removing items from a collection!

Comment: @willmel: You can just use a path like in code behind for the binding, if you expose the connection object as a property called `Connection`, the binding will just be `{Binding Connection.HasMovies, Converter=...}`.

Comment: @H.B. : So I tried doing this and creating a new property, but it does not seem to work.. It does not update with the property. Anything I'm doing wrong? {Binding Context.HasMovies, Converter={StaticResource OnOffConverter}}

Comment: @willmel: I do not know your full code; does the value get bound at first and just doesn't update or does the binding fail (see Output window in VS)?

Comment: @H.B. The value does not update. The binding does work correctly, however the first time, and subsequent views of the page.

Comment: @willmel: If you post the code of your classes somewhere (e.g. Pastebin) i could take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the setter for a collection type, such as your MovieList property, is **not** called when you change the *content* of the collection (ie. Add/Remove items).

This means all your setter code for the MovieList property is pointless.

Secondly, it's very silly code. A much better solution, is to use [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver). Then your code would look like this, in the viewmodel:

```
[DependsOn("MovieList")]
public bool HasMovies
{
    get { return MovieList != null && MovieList.Count > 0; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieList
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Alternatively you would have to add a listener for the CollectionChanged event when you initialize the MovieList property the first time (no reason to have a backing property, really really no reason!), and then call RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies") in the event handler.

Example:

```
public class CP : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CP()
    {
        MovieList = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
        MovieList.CollectionChanged += MovieListChanged;
    }

    public bool HasMovies
    {
        get { return MovieList != null && MovieList.Count > 0; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieList
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void MovieListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies");
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the setter of the collection? There a handler is hooked up to the CollectionChanged event, it should work...

Comment: I find it very unlikely the said setter will ever be called, considering he's using a backing field. Also, the RaisePropertyChanged("HasMovies"); in the setter wouldn't ever do anything useful. Either way, using NotifyProperWeaver is the most beautiful way of doing it.

Comment: @Claus. the [DependsOn("MovieList")] is actually redundant as NPW will derive that dependency

Comment: @Claus hows this? http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/wiki/PropertyDependencies